# What happend to Vegetarianism site's css?

Tags: bug, status-completed, beta-sites

I have been just been invited to Vegetarianism web site, but it fails to load the css:

URL = https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/

404 error URL for styles: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/vegetarian/all.css

Note: I have tried other sites from the network (SO, politics etc.) and they work fine.

Comment: Where are you getting the CSS URL from? The one I see is: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/vegetarianism/all.css?v=10522186908d

Comment: Note the difference - your URL has "vegetarian", mine has "vegetarianism".

Comment: The URL is reported by Chrome's Developer Console.

Comment: It came back to life. The style disappeared after submitting an answer, so I did not input the URL manually.

Comment: I happened. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there was a developer error there in setting the correct CSS path for the site.

It was corrected almost immediately.